# Installing armitage in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, software-installation, graphics, java

I’m trying to install armitage by following this procedure (video 6:51). Once I execute `sudo ./armitage`, I got the message :

```
The Parallel GC can not be combined with -XX:ParallelGCThreads=0.
```

What do I have to do to finalize the installation of this software?

Comment: Parallel gc has to do with java. Do you have metasploit and java installed? Oh and your video "link" doesn't work as it's just text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Oracle Java 1.8u131 as explained [in this blog post](https://blog.cobaltstrike.com/2017/04/26/java-startup-bug-in-java-1-8u131/):

> This recent update to Oracle’s Java introduces a change that breaks the `-XX:+AggressiveHeap` command line option [...] The Java team is aware of this bug and it has a priority level 2. This is the level reserved for crashes, losses of data, and severe memory leaks. They’re taking it seriously and I expect this problem to go away in a coming Java update.
>
> On Linux, one way to work around this Oracle Java bug is to update the cobaltstrike and teamserver scripts to specify the `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8` option after the java command.
>
> I advise that you stay away from Oracle Java 1.8u131. If you already updated to Java 1.8u131, then [downgrade to Java 1.8u121](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jdk-8u121-oth-JPR).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step video to downgrade to version 121 by nizar Mhymyd.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qItkpx61XQ0.